# Using a Jquery variable with ajax request

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I've got the following code within a Laravel web app, I'm creating.

```
function approverDelete(ctl) {
  var id = $(ctl).data("id");
  // Call Web API to delete a approver
  alert(id) // This gives expected result
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('delete.approvers', 'id') }}",
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function (approver) {
      $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
    },
    error: function (request, message, error) {
      handleException(request, message, error);
    }
  });
}
```

`id` should be evaluated to a integer and if I place an `alert(id)` just above this I get the expected value in the alert.

However, when this code runs, the actual request is for the url is being sent to `http://example.com/admin/approvers/delete/id` not the expected `http://example.com/admin/approvers/delete/9` (or whatever the `id` value is)

If I replace `url: "{{ route('approvers.delete', 'id') }},"` with `url: "http://example.com/admin/approvers/delete/"+id,` it works exactly as expected.

As far as I know it should work with the named route approach, in fact if I remove `id` when using the named route approach it errors with a missing parameter.

EDIT: Adding requested sources view

[image: Sources View]

EDIT2: Adding more information

So it appears that the problem is Larvel is treating `"{{ route('delete.approvers', 'id') }}"` as though it just use within the blade.

If I add

```
@php
$id = "test";
@endphp
```

Before the script block and change to `"{{ route('delete.approvers', $id) }}"` The $id will be evaluated as a variable and the request will be sent to the expected url.

Comment: did you try without qoutes to id?  `url: "{{ route('approvers.delete', id) }}"`

Comment: I did. I've wrapped `id` up everyway I can think of. When I don't wrap `id` in quotes it comes back as an undefined constant, but as I say I can literally `alert(id)` 1 line before this within the same function an it gives the expected result. I'll add a bit more code in to my question

Comment: I would write the route this way: route('delete.approvers', ['id' =>id] )

Comment: try this backtick here{{ route('delete.approvers', ${id} ) }} backtick close here, I can't use backticks in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Laravel parses the blade template it will parse anything inside `{{ }}`.

The `alert(id)` works because it isn't parsed by Laravel, this is why I was also getting an undefined constant when I put `id` instead of `'id'`. Once I removed the quote marks Laravel was treating it as a variable.

The Laravel docs do offer a way to deal with this by using `@{{ }}` but this seems to only be for use outside of the `script` block.

For now I'll have to hardcode the url until I can resolve it another way